# What files do I need to include with my Python app?

Tags: python, file, runtime

I have an app that uses the python/c api and I was wondering what files I need to distribute with it? The app runs on Windows and links with libpython31.a Are there any other files? I tried the app on a seperate Win2k system and it said that python31.dll was needed so theres at least one.

Edit - My app is written in C++ and uses the Python/C api as noted below.

Comment: Does the `distutils` command `python setup.py bdist_win` work for you?

Comment: Wait, wait, wait... it complains about python31.dll? That comes with Python, meaning that Python isn't installed. But then....how do you run it? Do you mean that this is a non-Python app, ie an EXE-file, that calls into Python?

Comment: OK, that's unclear from the question (as the C-API also works the other way, ie from Python), so you may want to update that. I think that the DLL is the only one, but I only read that and have never done it, so I don't know, so not an answer, just a comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to tell is to try it on 'clean' installations of windows and see what it complains about. Virtual machines are a good way to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and found out I need python31.dll and python31.zip which is an archive of the Libs folder.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need at least Python's own DLL (release-specific) and the wincrt DLL version it requires, also Python version depended (if you want to run on releases of Windows that don't come with that DLL).  The popular [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), the not-widely-know but hugely powerful [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (**NOTE**: use the svn version, **not** the released version which is aeons behind), and similar package-makers, do a good job of identifying and solving all such dependencies, so there's no case for doing it by hand!